# android studio button function not working in button.performClick()

Tags: android, button

`view.setBackground(COLOR.GREEN);` does not work when I use `button.performClick()` but works when I manually click the button. All other code works except the `.setBackground()` in `button.performClick()`.

Comment: Does your button have an `OnClickListener`?

Comment: @bibek where do you call performClick() ?

Comment: @Alex I do not have OnClickListener . But all other codes work only .setBackground does not

Comment: @Simo  in the protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState), because i want it to be clicked as soon as the app start.

Comment: Try to move the `performClick()` method from `onCreate` to `onStart` or `onResume`

Comment: @SimoV8 I think there is another problem because perform.onClick() calls the method all the time but only the view.setBackground does not work(all other stuff works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have no `OnClickListener` for you button. Here is the Javadoc for `performClick`:

> Added in API level 1
>
> **Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined**. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

Comment: I tried the OnClickListener but same thing. Everything works but the setBackground does not :( . Thank you though